# Moving Webdav app from Win server 2k to Win server 2k3 now getting authentication issues

Tags: iis-6, webdav

I have an intranet web app that uses CSS httpFolder to map a webdav folder to an IFrame on a web page. The user then can drop files in the frame and the page processes them when the user presses the button.

This works well on a Win 2k SP4 server running IIS 5.
I have moved the app over to a Win 2k3 server running IIS 6. I have made sure the WebDAV extensions are allowed. I have set everything else in IIS to match the original installation on the old server. But when I try to access the WebDAV folder I am repeatedly prompted for my login credentials. I use my domain admin login but even that doesn't work.

What am I missing? What differences are there between WebDAV on 2k vs 2k3?

TIA
John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After using Fiddler to see what was going on in the page requests I had to modify the web.config to recognize the missing verbs.

Comment: Would you be able to share how you updated your Web.config to allow the missing WebDAV verbs? I've got a custom WebDAV server setup on IIS 7, but now I'm trying to make it work in IIS 6 but not having much luck. I've got a question posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14204387/in-iis-6-force-all-incoming-requests-to-be-handled-by-asp-net